# express.js: Is the `app` property on request and response objects supported?

Tags: express

I’ve found that request and response objects in express have an `app` property referencing the express application they belong to.

Is that property regarded as stable part of the API, or might it go away in some future release? The [API docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html) don’t mention the property at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for here. It's not officially documented. Needing to use it is a fairly good sign that your design is tightly coupled. Might it go away in a future release? Yes, which is of course the case for, y'know, everything (and especially for node libraries). If you're waiting for TJ to show up and bless this as officially API that will not change for X years, you could be waiting a long time. If you need it, use it. If it goes away in the future, adjust accordingly. If you're planning on using `req.app` in hundreds of places in your app, there's a strong chance a redesign would eliminate that need.